# StrictModeDiskReadViolation when

Tags: android

I am trying to use SharedPreferences to store some user settings for my app. I have this code in my Activity.onCreate method:

```
sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MMPreferences", 0);
soundOn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("soundOn", true);
```

but it gives me this error (it is the getBoolean that generates the error):

```
11-10 16:32:24.652: D/StrictMode(706): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=229 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=2079 violation=2
```

and the result is that the value is not read and I also get the same error when I try to write to the SharedPreferences with this code (it is the commit that generates the error):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("soundOn", soundOn);
editor.commit();
```

The only answers for this error I can find is about a strict mode warning, but my code actually fails to read/write the SharedPreferences key/value data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should accessing SharedPreferences be done off the UI Thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371273/should-accessing-sharedpreferences-be-done-off-the-ui-thread)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must do fileSystem operations on a separate thread, then the error will go away.

you can also turn off the StrictMode (but i am not recommending that)

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy old = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(old)
    .permitDiskWrites()
    .build());
doCorrectStuffThatWritesToDisk();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(old);
```

Comment: Ok I now create a thread on Activity.onCreate and this thread reads properties in startup and checks for dirty properties and writes those if needed, and I stop the thread on Activity.onPause and start it again on Activity.onResume. Sounds about right?

Comment: It works for sure, and I have tested that the thread is not alive when the app is in the background so it looks good. Just wanted to hear if you wizards thought it sounded like a good way to do it ;)

Comment: @Frank what "doCorrectStuffThatWritesToDisk() " mean ?   Thanks

Comment: It is your "business logic" that writes things to the disk. Basicly i am turning off strict mode, write, turn strict mode back on.

Answer (score 5):

If you have reactive (RxJava)  configured in your Android project, you can take advantage of its properties like schedule a task on an I/O-specific Scheduler, for instance:

```
public void saveFavorites(List<String> favorites) {
    Schedulers.io().createWorker().schedule(() -> {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(Constants.FAVORITE, jsonFavorites);
        editor.apply();
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `editor.commit()` to avoid wasting another thread, since you're already there.