# How to fix Android compatibility warnings

Tags: android

I have an app that is targeting Android 9 and I noticed in the Google Play prelaunch report a new section called Android compatibility. This new section lists warnings or errors related to the usage of unsupported APIs. The following is one of the problems and is listed as a greylisted API. Can someone explain which is the unsupported API in this case? The usage seems to be coming from the Android support library and not my code.

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(ViewUtils.java:84)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:685)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:299)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:98)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3002)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: possibly duplicate, check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780934/finding-what-violated-strictmode-policy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780934/finding-what-violated-strictmode-policy

Comment: I do not think it is the same problem. The warning I have (note that it is a warning - I do not have any app crashes) is for a NonSdkApiUsedViolation- this is not the same as a StrictModeDiskReadViolation due to disk performing disk operations on the main thread. The warning comes up on the Google Play vitals section.

Comment: I have faced the same problem any solution you found till now...??

Answer (score 13):

I suppose there nothing we can do right now, just to wait that they fixed these issues in AndroidX (as Support Library won't be updated anymore).
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736775/43051) the methods use reflection, so why the warning.