# Compatibility issues in pre-launch report of my app: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation

Tags: android, compatibility, prelaunch

My Google Play pre-launch report came back with 10 Android compatibility warnings, including 4 of the following:

```
    StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ViewUtils.makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows(ViewUtils.java:84)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:827)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
at com.chiaramail.pento.FivetoGo.onCreate(FivetoGo.java:277)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

plus comments for Landroid/graphics/FontFamily, Landroid/graphics/Typeface, computeFitSystemWindows, PopupWindow->setClipToScreenEnabled and PopupWindow->setEpicenterBounds. I'm not directly calling any of these methods, so I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: See this question, I think it is the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/56130459/1172714 .  It appears to be an issue in the AndroidX appcompat libraries, not anything in your app itself.

Comment: Thanks, @dsh. I guess I'll just have to wait for a fix.