# Enable unsupported API warnings in Android Studio Lint

Tags: android-studio, lint

I'm getting a number of errors in the Google Play Console Pre-launch reports related to unsupported APIs.

The errors as listed in Pre-launch reports appear to give me no real usable (at least for me) clues as to where the errors are in my code.

This page https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#studio-lint suggests that Android Studio should possibly be giving me build errors or warnings, but I'm not seeing anything.

Do I need to enable these warnings in lint in AS or should it be enabled by default or does it require a minimum target API level in my project for these warnings to be flagged in the IDE? (My AS installation is fully up to date).

If not, is there an way that I can find a clue as to what code is generating these warnings?

Example warnings are:

`API Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V`

`API Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V`

`API Landroid/widget/AbsListView;->mIsChildViewEnabled:Z`

`API Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z`

`API Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;->selectionAction(III)Landroid/view/textclassifier/logging/SmartSelectionEventTracker$SelectionEvent;`

Searching for snippets of these errors across my source code yields no results so I am at a loss as to how to find and correct the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the two issues here *have* been answered elsewhere - I just wasn't looking in the right place, somehow.

Regarding the error(s) listed above - it seems that they are in the `AppCompat` support library and also in the `AndroidX` library. Google broke their own rules! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358496/setcontentview-is-using-non-sdk-interface).

As to enabling `strict mode`... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781338/2211491) answer describes that process.

So... ultimately it looks like Google needs to fix their library and that there is nothing really I can do myself to avoid these warnings if I intend to use `AppCompat` or `AndroidX` libraries, but in future I can look into things more deeply myself by enabling `strict mode`.